# Azure function Timer SQL client failing

Tags: azure-functions, azureportal, sqlclient

My .net core azure timer function is failing all of a sudden with this error.

System.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform.

I am not sure what changed and why it would start failing.

When I run the code locally it runs fine without errors. Ataching what I am seeing on Azure-Portal
[image]
Any suggestions?

Comment: What the version of System.Data.SqlClient you use?

Comment: also ensure that you are functions v2

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure what changed and why it would start failing.

According to your error message, it seems that you have upgrade your `System.Data.SqlClient` version like from 4.5.1 to 4.6.

If as I said, there seems some problem when it comes to references related to runtime assemblies, refer to this [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/2050#issuecomment-445153081).

If you don't need the latest stable version 4.6.0, simply revert to 4.5.1 would work.

Otherwise the workaround is to load the assemblies on our own. Right click on Function project and Edit .csproj, add items below to copy related assemblies to output dir.

```
<!-- For publish -->
    <ItemGroup>
        <None Include="$(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\system.data.sqlclient\4.6.0\runtimes\win\lib\netcoreapp2.1\System.Data.SqlClient.dll">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </None>
    </ItemGroup>

<!-- For local debug -->
    <Target Name="CopyToBin" BeforeTargets="Build">
        <Copy SourceFiles="$(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\system.data.sqlclient\4.6.0\runtimes\win\lib\netcoreapp2.1\System.Data.SqlClient.dll" DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)\bin" />
    </Target>
```